# C# Storing Folder Permissions

Tags: c#, permissions, directory-permissions

I'm having a little trouble with storing Folder Permissions. I was able to find a some documentation on writing them and reading them. What I'm trying to do is read the permissions on a folder for a specific user > Store it > change the permissions > after installer program finishes, change the permissions back.

I have all of it down (only due to code from many others) EXCEPT how to store the original folder permissions and set it back. I'll gladly read any material that you suggest, we receive several fatal errors with the software and this is one step to resolving many of them. All help is welcome and appreciated.

Below is an example of how I'm setting the permissions. Yes I know that I have everyone, but it is just for testing right now

```
 public void setPermDir()
    {
        try
        {
            string DirectoryName = "C:\\Temp1\\";

            Console.WriteLine("Adding access control entry for " + DirectoryName);

            // Add the access control entry to the directory.
            AddDirectorySecurity(DirectoryName, @"Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);


            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Adds an ACL entry on the specified directory for the specified account.
    public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
    {
        // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
        // current security settings.
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                        Rights,
                                                        ControlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return the DirectorySecurity dSecurity from AddDirectorySecurity then you could just call `Directory.SetAccessControl(directoryName, dSecurity);` once you were done with the modified access rules.

**Update**

If just SetAccessControl doesn't work the next step might be to explicitly remove the permissions you have granted using [FileSystemSecurity.RemoveAccessRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbfbabws.aspx).

Just keep a reference to the FileSystemAccessRule you create:

```
FileSystemAccessRule toRemoveWhenDone = new FileSystemAccessRule(Account, Rights, ControlType);
```

Comment: Yes, I am using that method. I just didn't see how to store the permission for a specific user.